# How to use php to output details of a form from HTML5

Tags: php, html

```
<form id="superheroForm" action="submit.php" method="post">
<p><i>Please complete the form. Mandatory fields are marked with a </i><em>*</em></p>
<fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Details</legend><br>
  <label for="Name">Name <em>*</em></label>
  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Jane "  autofocus required><br>
  <label for="telephone">Telephone <em>*</em></label>
  <input id="telephone" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" title="must be in the following format (xxx)-xxx-xxxx" 
  pattern=[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4} required><br>
  <label for="email">Email <em>*</em></label>
  <input id="email" type="email" required><br><br>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

I have another file named submit.php. Once the user clicks on submit application button, I am supposed to get the php response something like this: 
Thanks for submitting your form 
Name: 
Telephone:

So far I have tried this directly in a new file named submit.php but it doesn't work at all: This is my php code:

```
<html>
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
</html>
</body>
```

Update:Solution: Sorry I did not install PHP the right way.

Comment: where is `</form>` and  why is there an extra `<fieldset>`

Comment: show me your php code

Comment: can you post your submit.php code? if you type input into the html form, does it take you to a blank page at least?

Comment: you need `<?php ....`

Comment: @ceeks update your question with submit.php code for better help :)

Comment: @YangfanCheng if you see my updated question for the php code, you can see I tried that too, but form just redirects me to a new page with the code posted rather than name and email address

Comment: your server might not be configured properly to run php

Comment: you probably running it on local computer?

Comment: Sorry guys, php was configured on my server or something. Just got it fixed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

your php code should contain something like this

```
<?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
//then just echo them
   echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your superhero form like this..

```
<form id="superheroForm" action="submit.php" method="post">
<p><i>Please complete the form. Mandatory fields are marked with a </i><em>*</em></p>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Details</legend><br>
<label for="Name">Name <em>*</em></label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Jane "  autofocus required>  <br>
<label for="telephone">Telephone <em>*</em></label>
<input id="telephone"  placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" name="tel" required><br>
<label for="email">Email <em>*</em></label>
<input id="email" type="email" required><br><br>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

and Your submit.php is like this

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['name'])){
      echo "Thanks for submitting your form ";
      echo "Name:".$_POST['name'];
      echo "Telephone:".$_POST['tel'];
    }
?>
```

This is it.

Comment: Hey i tried your php code, and it redirects me to a new page which just shows me your code

Comment: It would be better if you can point out the mistake. so he and future readers don't make the same mistake again. and few links to reference will also be useful :)

Comment: @ceeks you sure? coz this should work, check if php is installed.

Comment: using echo with escape character like "\n"
ie; echo "Name\n"; like this